# Implementing a DDOS protection on a private linux server

Tags: networking, cdn, cloudflare, ddos

I am hosting a private linux server which only has an IP. No domain name. Is it possible to implement a service Cloufflare/Akamai on my server to protect it from DDoS and other attacks ? If yes, how acn I do it ?

Answer (score -1):

You can only Protect your server against `Layer 7` DDoS attacks via [Cloudflare](https://cloudflare.com/) and an Domain. Cloudflare is free and **hides** your real IP.

There is also [Cloudflare Spectrum](https://www.cloudflare.com/de-de/products/cloudflare-spectrum/) which protects your server against `Layer 4` DDoS attacks.